# Errors running tests after upgrading Jest

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

I upgraded Jest to 24.1, and babel via `npx babel-upgrade --write`.  My unit tests that use async functions are failing with:

`ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` . I have googled around the error, and there are some older information dealing with beta 7 versions or beta 6 of babel.  How do I fix the error?

For reference my package.json and babel.rc files are located [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zw5rqvnmzl?fontsize=14)

Comment: Please paste config file contents instead of providing links.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by adding to my babel.rc file:

```
["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", { "corejs": 2 }]
```

and then adding them as devDependencies:

```
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.3.4",
"@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.3.4",
```